# Application controls are getting identified differently by CodedUi Test Builder

Tags: unit-testing, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am not able to Identify correct control of an application by Coded Ui Test Builder

[Seee this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGQpk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below are possible reasons:

- Check system display settings front icon size, Display resolution
- There may be hidden control with same search properties. Try add more properties